# Can I install both Visual Studio stable and alpha on the same Mac?

Tags: macos, visual-studio

Sometimes I want to use Visual Studio alpha version to use latest update, but most of the time I want to use stable version.

By changing `Update channel`, it always download all libraries.
Is there a way to install both stable and alpha version in MacOS Sierra?

I only found the information about Windows.
https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/